# Flutter Google Maps showing blank screen for app bundle?

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, dart, android-app-bundle

The debug version works fine and I've added the debug and release SHA-1 fingerprint to the cloud console. When I run flutter build apk --release and install the apk on my device, google maps works fine. However if I run flutter build appbundle and install the aab on my device, google maps just shows a blank screen. Whats the likely cause of this problem?

Update:
I just switched the restrictions to none and everything works so its probably a problem with a SHA-1 entry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Internet permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file.
Go to your project app->src->main->AndroidManifest.xml. Paste the following after  and before .